# Quickblox, adding custom fields to Users and Chat tables

Tags: android, chat, real-time, quickblox

I'm trying to use Quickblox to create my personal chat app, but I have faced a small problem and that is I want to add some fields in the group chat and the user table, like for the group chat I want to assign an admin, so I will save the admin ID and I want to have categories for my groups and in the user table I want to add the mobile number, selected wallpaper.
How can I add custom fields in Quickblox classes using android code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool that allows to add custom parameters:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Android_XMPP_Chat_Sample#Custom_parameters

Comment: Links are subject to change/expire. Please add description to your answer here itself

Comment: @stas I tried it out but I think the custom parameters are getting saved because when I retreive them using getData() and try to access the fields I get a null pointer exception.